# How to print some set of vectors with format?

Tags: python, arrays, printing, format

I´ve been trying to print 2 vectors in a table-like format.
The trouble comes when elements from list A and list B don´t have the same ammount of floats

```
import math
def f(x):
    y=1/(math.sqrt(1+x))
    return y
xmin=0.0
xmax=1.0
print "Write some n:"
n=input()
x=[]
delta=((xmax-xmin)/n)
for i in range (n):
    xx=xmin+i*delta
    x.append(xx)
y=[]
b=f(x[0])
y.append(b)
for i in range (1,n-1):
    yy=2*f(x[i])
    y.append(yy)
y.append(f(x[n-1]))
for i in range(n):
    print x[i],y[i]
```

The problems comes when printing the last line:
What I want:

```
0.0     1.0

0.125   1.88561808316

0.25    1.788854382
```

What I get:

```
0.0 1.0

0.125 1.88561808316

0.25 1.788854382
```

How can I fix those digits, so the program prints the result properly?
Thanks :)

Comment: print x, "    ", y, with the amount of spaces between quotes

Comment: I tried adding the spaces, but it was pretty much the same due to digits. And thank you so much for the link, I tried searching in a lot of ways how to fix this, but missed that link.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) to do that.
The following would set the padding to 6 places:

```
print(”{:6}{:6}".format(x[i ], y[I]))
```

Comment: Appreciate the edit Alex. I couldn't get the formatting to work on my phone, I had planned on editing it when I got to my computer.